# How does auto.arima deal with integrated time series in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

From my experience, when a time series $T$ is integrated/has a unit-root, one cannot model it with an ARMA model can usually need to turn to the first difference of $T$ (or some research I read uses $ln(T)$).

However, I just realized recently that in R's `auto.arima` function (under the "forecast" package), it is possible to run an ARIMA regression with covariates (by specifying the parameter `xreg`) **even if** the time series is integrated (e.g. an ARIMA(2,1,2) process).

My question is:

1. Does this model still yield valid statistical results about the covariates' coefficients?
2. If valid, how does `auto.arima` deal with the integrated process? I think it is probably not taking the first difference, but am not sure what is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `auto.arima()` does not fit an ARIMAX model, but a regression on the covariates with ARIMA errors. See Rob Hyndman's ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) blog post for the difference.

So you should be somewhat careful about inference for covariate coefficients, since standard $t$ tests assume iid errors, and the errors in your `auto.arima()` model are ARIMA. Note that `auto.arima()` reports estimated coefficients and their standard errors, but no $t$ statistics or $p$ values.

As to how `auto.arima()` deals with potential integration, a look at `?auto.arima` is helpful:

```
   d: Order of first-differencing. If missing, will choose a value
      based on KPSS test.
```

The KPSS test is of course standard, since it is applied to the residuals of the regression on your covariates.